# Sharepoint 2013 Developer Edition

Tags: development, 2013

Most of the Microsoft tools have developer editions available in MSDN subscriptions, but I dont seem to find one for SharePoint.

I was just wondering how people do their development if they dont have license. in my case, I will start learning 2013 development, but I dont want to use foundation as it is quite feature limited. I can install trial version of SharePoint but it, I believe, expires in 180 days. Do you just simply install trial on a VM and reuse it?

your thoughts will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend to start with foundation. It will cover 90% of your scenarios as a beginning developer.

Later on, you can try to get familiar with trial version and play with metadata and other features available in this version.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN and/or TechNet versions of SharePoint - by definition - are to be used for test, development or demo environments. There is no separate development version available. So if you have such a subscription, just use the included versions.

Btw, if you're starting out in development for SharePoint, starting with the foundation version is not necessarily a bad idea in my opinion. SharePoint is a big beast so starting out with the basics might be beneficial to you.